# Go install and resources folder

Tags: go

I have a programme with some resources in separate folder, I'd like to encourage potential users to use  `go get` + `go install` (in spirit of golang and without makefile), so binary must to know absolute path to my resources directory, for now I have something like this:

```
data := os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/project_name/path_to_resources/"
```

Is there any other (proper) way to do this?

Comment: If the resource folder is inside your project you can use relative paths instead of absolute paths. I do recommend you have a look at [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor) to install dependencies.

Comment: Your binary has no knowledge of the source directory, and in most deployments there won't even be a source directory. It's up to the user deploying the application to supply required external resources separately from `go get` or `go install`.

Comment: @vonaka: normally a program has some flexible method of finding resources, be it either a default search path, a flag, an environment variable, or a combination of the three. It's is up to you to document how your program works.

Comment: @vonaka: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Libraries that you want to share should always be `go get`-able to install the source, but there's no reason you shouldn't have to read the docs to learn how to use the package. Simple binary tools may work completely via `go get` (`go install` is run as part of the `go get` process), but larger go projects often include Makefiles or build scripts once the basic build tools no longer suffice.